# NGINX location {} different root directory

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to change the root directory of a location for example:

```
location /test/ {
 root /var/www/test/
}
```

the above doesn't seem to work.
The default root directory is `/var/www/html`
and the files I'm trying to access are in `/var/www/test/`, what kind of commands should I use to essentially change the root location of a directory?
I hope you understand what I'm trying to accomplish.
Any help is widely appreciated.

Comment: are you getting a load error of you file? try: location /test/ {
 root /var/www/test;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case you should use the alias directive instead of another root.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
location /test {
 alias /var/www/test;
}
```

Comment: ```location /test/ {
        alias /var/www/html/web-config/;
}
``` this is what I did, didn't seem to work, I'm running nginx on docker btw

Comment: without the ending / in your test location. Can you try it again?